# Django Development - Admin CSS file 404

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using [this guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/) to attempt to get this working. Basically, I'm exploring django 1.6 (with python 2.7.6 on Mac OS X Yosemite beta), still working with the stock development server. I'm trying to include a CSS file to override some styles in the admin area. I have a `static` folder in my *project* root. My settings.py is completely stock (that means I have DEBUG set to true and that I'm using `django.contrib.staticfiles`). Inspecting the source and request/response reveals that I'm calling for the CSS file at my expected path, but that I'm getting a 404 when attempting to load it. I also get a 404 when attempting to hit the CSS file directly in the browser. I've searched google and SO and have not, as of yet, been able to find an answer.

The requested CSS file:

`http://*mysite*/static/admin/css/mysite-admin.css`

The file system path to the CSS file:

`*myprojectdir*/static/admin/css/mysite-admin.css`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it won't work because Django does not serve by default static assets, in order to have static assets served (mind though this should be the case only for local dev) in your main urls.py file add this to the top:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
```

And then at the end of your urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  # NOQA
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    ) + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns
```

Make sure you have defined STATIC_URL, MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in your settings.py, for development STATIC_ROOT IS NOT needed.